# How to copy all non-alphanumeric characters at the begining of the line to the next line?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, filetype-markdown

I want to implement something similar to Org mode M-RET into neovim. In Org mode it creates new list item or heading depending on what line the point is on.

I'm thinking of a mapping in neovim that copies everything from the beginning of the current line until the first alphanumeric character of the line and puts it on a new line. For example, with cursor at the end, it would transform this:

```
* list item
    * inner list item
```

into this:

```
* list item
    * inner list item
    *
```

I think it could be done with `:s` but i couldn't make it work (`:s/(^[^\w]*)(.*)/\1\2\n\1`) and it would replace the whole line, which is unnecessary.

Ideally it should work in insert mode and shouldn't rewrite any registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with this:

```
function! NewBullet()
    let l = getline('.')
    let l = substitute(l, '\w.*$','', '')
    return "\n" . l
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <F1> NewBullet()
```

Map-expression calls the function and inserts the returned text. Here a newline and the prefix of the line.

See `:help :map-expression`.

Comment: Perfect, except the new line has double indentation because of autoindent. I added another substitute command to remove all whitespace at the begining of the line.

Answer (score 1):

### `:substitute` Command

The problem with the command you tried is that you used `\n` where you needed to use `\r`. (See `:help s/\r`.)

I don't really share your aversion to substituting the entire line, but we'll avoid that too:

```
:s/\v^(\W*).*\zs/\r\1
```

### Insert Mode Mapping

To use this from insert mode, you can include it in an insert mode mapping:

```
:inoremap <F1> <Esc>:s/\v^(\W*).*\zs/\r\1<CR>A
```

### How It Works

- `\v` – using "very magic"
- `^` – the start of the line
- `(\W*)` – as many non-alphanumeric characters* as possible, grouped into a capture group.
- `.*` – as many characters as possible (i.e. the rest of the line)
- `\zs` – set the start of the match (and thus the start of the replacement) to here

The replacement:

- `\r` – A newline
- `\1` – The captured group.

<sub>* `\W` is equivalent to [0-9A-Za-z_] which is close enough to "non-alphanumeric" for your purposes.</sub>

### Avoid `:substitute` Entirely

It's also possible just to use regular editing commands to perform this task:

```
:inoremap <F1> <Esc>0y/\w<CR>o<Esc>pA
```

To see how this works, just try typing out the commands in the mapping's `rhs` manually!

Comment: I don't have aversion to substituting the entire line, i just think it could be done better, but it's better than overwriting registers.

Comment: @matj1 Neither solution in my answer substitutes the entire line.

Comment: If you don’t want the code to overwrite *any* registers, including the yank, unnamed, and search pattern registers, you’ll need a function that saves them before performing the edit and restores them afterwards.